# Web API error - Server Error in '/api' Application

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

After publishing Web API to IIS, which is a child of an AngularJs IIS site, I can reach 'https://localhost/api' and see all endpoints; but when I try to reach some specific endpoint with a `GET` request, I get an error

> Server Error in '/' Application

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/branches")]
public class BranchesController : ApiBaseController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("getBranches")]
    public async Task<JsonResult<List<BranchDto>>> GetActiveBranches()
    {
        var branches = new List<BranchDto>();

        var models = await WarehouseUnitOfWork.BranchRepository.GetActiveBranches();
        if (models != null && models.Count > 0)
        {
            branches.AddRange(AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<Branch>, List<BranchDto>>(models));
        }

        return Json(branches, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new WarehouseCustomContractResolver()
        });
    }
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Did you try `http://localhost/api` instead of `https://localhost/api`?

Comment: Yes I've already tried. What else can I do?

Comment: Can you post your API code?

Comment: @VoiceOfTheRain Do you want to see a specific controller?

Comment: Post your web api routing config along with one of your API controllers

Comment: @VoiceOfTheRain Here is routing config:
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config){
            config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
            config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi",routeTemplate:"api/{controller}/{id}",defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: @VoiceOfTheRain Here is an example of API controller:

[RoutePrefix("api/branches")]
    public class BranchesController : ApiBaseController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getBranches")]
        public async Task<JsonResult<List<BranchDto>>> GetActiveBranches(){}
}

Comment: Please post the code within your question by editing it

Answer (score 1):

The solution for my case was to deploy the Frontend into the main IIS site, and inside it create an application called `v1` for the Backend.
Then within my angularJS I defined the Production app to make the http requests to `/v1/api` instead of `/api`.

[image]